# Android Java SQLite searching / matching question

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I'm trying to search through a column where the string is a comma separated list of words with no spaces such as one,two,three,four and so on. Problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to match an exact word in the string. As of now I'm simply using %word% to find a match which of course works but the problem is it isn't exact in that if I searched for 'word' it would also match 'words', 'worded' and so on. So question is how can I search and get the exact word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append and prepend a comma to the string value in the column and then search it for your term which also has comma on either side of it:

```
   one,two,three,twofold
```

becomes

```
  ,one,two,three,twofold,
```

and you search for

```
   %,two,%


 where ',' + mycolumn + ',' like '%,two,%'

edit: in SQLite replace '+' with '||' (pipe pipe): where ',' || mycolumn || ',' like  '%,two,%'
```

You don't have to alter ("tamper with") the database record itself.

P.S. Wildcard on both sides of search term eliminates possibility of using an index to speed the search, so this approach is not recommended on large datasets.  But then again, neither is a comma-delimited list :-)

P.P.S. I don't know what device you're using, of course, or the size of your table, but on a PC several years old it takes SQlite 8ms to search through 3000 records using this comma-concatenation approach.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that but I was just wondering if there was a solution that didn't involve tampering with the string

Comment: See my comment in the answer.

Comment: This is an ok solution but the first and last entries will be excluded from the search.  `%,one,%` won't match `one,` , etc

Comment: @yep, you're wrong about that because the approach prepends and appends a comma to the column's content.

Comment: Ohhh I fully see what you did there now.  Yeah, you're right.  Seems a bit hacky though, but then again CSV list as 1 field is kinda hacky too.

Comment: Right.  Once you let comma-delimited lists into the database, it's gonna get ugly.

Comment: I did as suggested but it crashes out FROM notes WHERE ',' tags ',' LIKE '%work%' ORDER BY modified DESC if I take out the ',' it works though but obviously the problem is still in place

Comment: Of course its a syntax error.  You need to concat the strings  :)  `+`

Comment: Sorry, but I'm sort of a newb at sqlite and don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Without your whole select statement I can't help you completely. But you need something like: `String mySqlStmt = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ','+datacolumn+',' like '%,two,%'"` Note the usage of single and double quotes.  And replace it with the name of your datacolumn and table, and other such SQL syntax you are doing

Comment: @Paul: you need to use the "concatenation operator" which is || in SQLite instead of the plus sign.

Answer (score 1):

There is a design problem here. The database structure is not correct for what you're trying to achieve. Storing multiple values in a column and trying to match single values is possible with some other database as MySQL (with the SET type), but it's not on SQLite. So you could try all sort of weird string matching solution, but it won't be clean, and you will not be able to take advantage of SQLite optimizations. It will affect performance.

What you could use instead is a separate `words` table which contain a unique record for each word and another `foobar_words` table to establish a many-to-many relation between the words and your main `foobar` table. Then you could match individual words precisely by using a join. And if there are performance problems, with this schema you should be able to optimize with indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with the string, you could modify your sql so that you are looking `where mycolumn like 'word,%' or mycolumn like '%,word,%' or mycolumn like '%,word'`

Comment: This is definitely wrong, given a list:  `one,two,three,twofold,anyone,derp` 

searching for 'one' with your params would return one, anyone... searching for 'two' would return two, twofold, etc

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I misplaced the wildcard on the last param.  The example is fixed now.

Comment: Ok yeah now it is correct.   I think the other solution would probably be better on runtime, though, matching 3 likes per row with unindexed large strings has gotta be murder on SQLite

Comment: I agree, (actually, I think a little normalizing is the right answer), but if Paul would prefer not to modify the string, this is a possibility.